# Email a text file's content in html format

Tags: html, vbscript, html-table, html-email

I have a text file as:

**output.txt:**

```
OPERATING SYSTEM       SERVER1    SERVER2
Windows                  1.36       4.42
Linux                    2.78       5.76
MacOS                    3.45       6.39
Ubuntu                   4.12       0.00
Android                  0.00       3.46
FreePhysicalMemory      30.12      31.65
TotalVisibleMemorySize  48.00      48.00
```

I want to send content of Output.txt in a email as a body sothat its format (alignment) doesn't get changed (like an HTMIL table format):
i am trying with below code. Mail sent but in mail body getting nothing..what is error below ?

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Const ForAppending = 8
Dim objEmail, i
Set objEmail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
objEmail.Textbody = myTextBody
objEmail.HTMLBody = myHTMLBody
If IsArray( myAttachment ) Then
For i = 0 To UBound( "c:\output.txt" )
.AddAttachment Replace( "c:\output.txt" ( i ), "" ),"",""
 Next
ElseIf myAttachment <> "" Then
.AddAttachment Replace( "c:\output.txt", ""),"",""
End If
objEmail.TO ="sunny@abc.com"
objEmail.From = "dontreply@abc.com (CCP Stored Procedure Message)"
objEmail.Subject = "CCP Stored Procedure"
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration     /sendusing") = 2 
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtpb.intra.abc.com"
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration /smtpserverport") = 25 
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Update     
objEmail.Send
Set objEmail = Nothing
```

**EDIT1**

With below code, i am getting email as follows ..

```
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
Dim fso, f , objCDO1 ,BodyText
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objCDO1 = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
BodyText = fso.OpenTextFile("c:\Output.txt",ForReading).ReadAll
BodyText = "<html><body>" + BodyText  + "</body></html>"
objCDO1.HTMLBody = BodyText
objCDO1.TO ="sunny@abc.com"
objCDO1.From = "dontreply@bt.com (HFM)"
objCDO1.Subject = "StatS"
objCDO1.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
objCDO1.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtpb.abc.com"
objCDO1.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
objCDO1.Configuration.Fields.Update                  
objCDO1.Send
Set f = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
```

**email**

```
OPERATING SYSTEM SERVER1 SERVER2 Windows 1.36 4.42 Linux 2.78 5.76 MacOS 3.45 6.39  Ubuntu 4.12 0.00 Android 0.00 3.46 FreePhysicalMemory 30.12 31.65 TotalVisibleMemorySize  48.00 48.00
```

why not getting email as output.txt format ?

**EDIT2**

When I am using below in **EDIT1**..its working.

```
BodyText = fso.OpenTextFile("c:\Output.txt",ForReading).ReadAll
objCDO1.HTMLBody = "<html><body><pre>" & BodyText & "</pre></body></html>"
```

But..when I am using below in **EDIT1**..its not working.

```
BodyText = fso.OpenTextFile("c:\Output.txt",ForReading).ReadAll
objCDO1.HTMLBody = "<html><body><font size="12"><pre>" & BodyText & "</pre></font></body></html>"
```

Comment: What are the values of `myTextBody` and `myHTMLBody`? Do you have an `On Error Resume Next` in your code? Because `.AddAttachment Replace( "c:\output.txt" ( i ), "" ),"",""` can't possible work. Also there are spaces in the schema URL for the `sendusing` field that don't belong there.

Comment: Hi Ansgar..I changed the way..!pls see **EDIT1**...:)

Comment: Change `size="12"` to `size='12'` or `size=""12""`. Double quotes in VBScript strings must be escaped (by doubling them). However, in HTML code it's simpler to replace them with single quotes.

Comment: @Ansgar..tried ..but i wonder no html font type , font face etc. tag is working here..in every case mail is coming in default **courier new font size 10** format.should i go for Powershell..?.:)

Comment: Now I simply want to make it in **<font face='Arial'> and <font size='10'>**.

Comment: `<font face='Arial' size='10'>...</font>` should work. If it's not displayed correctly on the recipient side you need to inspect the source code of the mail on that side. It could be that something between sender and recipient is removing/modifying HTML. It could also be that the recipient's client configuration enforces a particular format. This would be a different question, though, and one that's better suited for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: Not working Ansgar..i think i need to be satisfied with default **courier new font size 10** format..:(..If only i could change font size=12 for **courier new** itself..that would have also been much better..because **font size 10** for **courier new** seems to be little small..:(..anyway..thanks for your help..! :)

Comment: ..and when I drop the HTML altogether and send the message as plain text..then font type and size are perfect but table data are coming not properly aligned in column.

Comment: +The magic is HTML Bold tag **<b>...</b>** is working..:'(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML doesn't work the way you seem to expect. For one thing, the parser collapses all consecutive whitespace to a single space, so something like

```
OPERATING SYSTEM       SERVER1    SERVER2
Windows                  1.36       4.42
Linux                    2.78       5.76
```

becomes

```
OPERATING SYSTEM SERVER1 SERVER2 Windows 1.36 4.42 Linux 2.78 5.76
```

when displayed.

If you want spaces/newlines preserved, change

```
BodyText = fso.OpenTextFile("c:\Output.txt",ForReading).ReadAll
BodyText = "<html><body>" + BodyText  + "</body></html>"
objCDO1.HTMLBody = BodyText
```

into

```
BodyText = fso.OpenTextFile("c:\Output.txt",ForReading).ReadAll
objCDO1.HTMLBody = "<html><body><pre>" & BodyText & "</pre></body></html>"
```

or drop the HTML altogether and send the message as plain text.

Comment: yes..now i am getting my email in format as output.txt..thanks Ansgar..!!

Comment: @Sunny The crucial part of my suggestion are the `<pre></pre>` tags.

Comment: @Ansgar..ohh..sorry for the typo..pls see **EDIT2**.